# Proving that µ(A ∩ B) is a measure

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

I'm currently working out exercise 3.6 from Bass' Real analysis for graduate
students. The problem is as follows:

Prove that if (X, ***A*** , µ) is a measure space, B ∈ ***A***, and we define ν(A) = µ(A ∩ B) for A ∈ ***A***, then ν is a measure.

I understand the concept behind a σ-algebra, and the relation between the measureable set and µ. However, I have hit a roadblock when trying to apply the information to this problem.

My issue is mainly figuring out where to start on this problem. I initially tried changing A ∩ B to (A' ∪ B')' ( where ' denotes the complement of a set) in order to expand this out/attempt to simplify it in some way. However, I am not sure I'm quite on the right track.

Any hints/tips you could give me would be much appreciated. Also, here is [Bass' book](https://www.uwo.ca/math/faculty/adamus/teaching/4122B2018/Bass-RealAnalysis3rd.pdf) for reference.

Comment: What are the conditions that a function on a $\sigma$-algebra has to satisfy in order to be a measure? Have you tried to verify any of them for $\nu$? You need to use the fact that $\mu$ satisfies these conditions in order to show that $\nu$ satisfies them.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @KeenanKidwell I know that µ(∅) = 0 and the pairwise disjoint sets of  **_A_** must be countably additive for µ to be a measure. Looking at those (and considering your comment) my first thought is to say that µ(A ∩ B) = 0 only if A and B are disjoint. Then from there I can work out condition two. Would that be too much of a logical jump, or is it valid to start from there?

Comment: Where to start on the problem? I would start by looking up the definition of a measure space and then write down what I know about $X$, $\mathbf A$, $\mu$ and what I have to prove about $\nu$.

Comment: Why do you want to say that $\mu(A\cap B)=0$ only if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint? That's not generally true, is it? In the case of Lebesgue measure on the line, what is $\mu(A\cap B)$ if $A=[1,2]$ and $B=[2,3]$?

Comment: Why don't you start by proving that $\nu(\emptyset)=0$?

Comment: After that, you might try thinking about how to prove that, if $A_1\cap A_2=\emptyset$, then $\nu(A_1\cup A_2)=\nu(A_1)+\nu(A_2)$? Yes, I know, you have to prove **countable** additivity, and this isn't it; but you have to walk before you can run.

Comment: @bof I just did a quick review of measures one more time and I see the error in my initial thought now. I see what you mean about proving ν(∅)=0. Because A would be empty in this case it is actually very straightforward. Thank you! I'm looking at the rest of it now, but I am starting to get a grasp of what I need to do here.

Answer (score 1):

We have to prove that 1) $v(\emptyset)=0$; 2)$v$ is positive and 3)$v$ is countably addictive. I think you know how to do 1 and 2... For 3:

Given a sequence $(A_i)$ of disjoint sets , $v(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i)=\mu(B\cap\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i)=\mu(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}B\cap A_i)$ and how $ B\cap A_i$ is a family of disjoints, we get the desired.

Comment: why downvote? Whats wrong?

Comment: This type of downvoting is becoming too common. I have given you an upvote.